# fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals for assembly language using VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
Comment @
Using Programming Exercise 6 in Chapter 4 as a starting point, 
write a program that generates the first 47 values in the Fibonacci 
series, stores them in an array of doublewords, and writes the 
doubleword array to a disk file.
@

INCLUDE c:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

FIB_COUNT = 47  ; number of values to generate

.data
fileHandle DWORD ?
filename BYTE "fibonacci.bin",0
array DWORD FIB_COUNT DUP(?)

.code
main2sub PROC

; Generate the array of values

mov esi, OFFSET array
mov ecx, LENGTHOF array
call generate_fibonacci

; Create the file, call CreateOutputFile

mov edx,OFFSET filename
call CreateOutputFile
mov fileHandle, eax

; Write the array to the file, call WriteToFile

mov eax, fileHandle
mov edx, OFFSET array
mov ecx, FIB_COUNT * 4
call WriteToFile

; Close the file, call CloseFile    

mov eax, fileHandle
call CloseFile

exit
main2sub ENDP

;------------------------------------------------------------
generate_fibonacci PROC USES eax ebx ecx edx
;
; Generates fibonacci values and stores in an array.
; Receives: ESI points to the array, 
;           ECX = count
; Returns: nothing
;------------------------------------------------------------


mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, 0

L1:
add ebx, ecx
mov [esi], eax

call WriteDec
call Crlf

inc esi
xchg ebx, eax

loop L1     ;end of looping

    ret
generate_fibonacci ENDP

END main2sub
```

It is my first semester learning about Assembly Language. Im not sure what to do with this error message "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals". Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `INCLUDELIB c:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib` ?

Comment: What is the entire error message you receive? It contains the name of the unresolved external.

Comment: C:\Users\Jong\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Fibonnaci_Number\Debug\Fibonnaci_Number.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 2):

The linker couldn't find the library-files `Irvine32.lib`, `Kernel32.Lib` and/or `User32.Lib`. They are in the same folder as `Irvine32.inc`

The easiest way is to inform ML about those libraries with a MASM-directive. Insert following three lines right behind the `INCLUDE c:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc`:

```
INCLUDELIB c:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib
INCLUDELIB c:\Irvine\Kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB c:\Irvine\User32.lib
```

Comment: I still get same error massage after including those 3 lines

Comment: @pooya13: Then you should tell us **all** error message(s). It should look like: *Irvine32.lib(Irvine32.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MessageBoxA@16 referenced in function _MsgBox@0*. The lazy way is to copy all messages from Visual Studio and paste them into your question.

Comment: sorry rkhb... 
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Jong\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Fibonnaci_Number\Debug\Fibonnaci_Number.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

this is the full error message

Comment: @pooya13: It seems that you've wrongly inserted the assembly file into the Visual Studio project. Do as Irvine does: http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2010/index.htm. Scroll to "Building a Sample Assembly Language Program" and especially consider "... select Existing Item ...".